# Delete row in email signature from HTML being read from Directory (AD)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html-table

I am trying to delete a row in html via jquery or javascript. I'm reading from a directory, but if there's no information within a row, I don't want it to be visible. Let's just assume I have two rows, and a user within the directory doesn't have a mobile number, how to remove it for them?

I have genuinely tried so many things but I must be missing something.

```
<tr>
   <td>email: %%email%%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>mobile: %%MobileNumber%%</td>
</tr>
```

I would assume the row would delete just for the user without a mobile number.

Comment: show the js. You can access trs by $.("table > tr > td:nth-of-type(2)").html("");

Comment: That's not a valid html structure. You have `<tr>` and `<td>` relationship reversed. Trying to use js on invalid structures will have inconsistent results due to how browser actually treats the rendering of them

Comment: The title should give a brief summary of the problem and not tell a completely unrelated story -> [Help Center - How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: so what is `%%MobileNumber%%` ..... my guess whatever you are using to spit it out should not do it....

Comment: @charliefl that's my bad, I was in a hurry to write it.

Comment: @epascarello the %%MobileNumber%% reads the information from a directory

Comment: @Andreas I misread the layout instructions

Comment: @SaschaGrindau I tried it but it didn't work, I do not have a definite js code as they didn't work sadly.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @Souleste none yet sadly

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the text as a variable, then find the substring after the ":" which will return the %%MobileNumber%%.

If the substring is empty, then we hide it.

As you can see the third `td` does not have the required text, so it is hidden.

```js
$(function() {

  $('td').each(function() {
    var str = $(this).text();
    var sub = str.substring(
      str.indexOf(':', 1) + 1
    );
    if (sub == '') {
      // or .remove()
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>email: %%email%%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>mobile: %%MobileNumber%%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>mobile:</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And if you only want it for the td containing "mobile:"

```
// find if a td starts with "mobile:" and if the substring after is empty
if ( str.match("^mobile:") && sub == '' ) {
    $(this).hide();
}
```

Comment: Hey! I just attempted this and no luck, thanks for trying, not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Really? What exactly is your data inserting into the td?

Comment: we are gathering information from the Azure Directory by using the '%%MobileNumber%%' term and displaying it in the td. We are doing first name, last name, etc. and if a user doesn't have a mobile number it wouldn't show the 'm: ' line.

Comment: When you tried this, where did you put the code, before or after the text (%%MobileNumber%%) was loaded in?

Comment: I put it before and after and didn't work for me sadly. Just curious, does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Add a id to the row you want to hide, put the `mobile:` outside `<td>` then use JQuery to achieve the same

```
<tr id="hideIfNoData"> 
     mobile:<td> %%MobileNumber%%</td> 
</tr>

$('#hideIfNoData > tr td:empty').parent().hide()
```

Comment: $(function(){
    $('#hideIfNoData tr').each(function(){
        var val = $(this).text().trim();
        if(val == 'mobile:'){
            $(this).remove();
        }
    })
})                           try something like this

Comment: sadly no luck with that one either

Comment: put the mobile: outside <td> and check if td is empty then remove the entire <tr>

Comment: <tr id="hideIfNoData">
  mobile: <td> %%MobileNumber%%</td>
</tr>$('#hideIfNoData > tr td:empty').parent().hide()

Comment: @RajendraGupta You can't have text nodes as direct children of `<tr>`